# Distribution of a Modified Binomial Random Walk with Variable Step Sizes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

Consider a variation of the binomial random walk.

In the traditional binomial random walk, each step has a consistent step size (let's assume this size is 1), and there's an equal probability of moving either to the left or the right. We can represent this as:

${\displaystyle {S = X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}}}$
​

where $X_{i}$ are independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables.

In our modified version of the binomial random walk, the step sizes differ.

What would the distribution look like for this modified binomial random walk? It this distribution related to some well-known distribution ?

Comment: Hi: You should explain how they differ ? is the step size a random variable ?

Comment: step size for for n-th step is 1/n^2.

Comment: This paper considers a case that bears  resemblance to your problem but the function is not $\frac{1}{n^2}$. It looks very complicated at a glance. . http://physics.bu.edu/~redner/pubs/pdf/golden.pdf#:~:text=This%20article%20discusses%20the%20properties%20of%20random%20walks,is%20a%20monotonic%20but%20otherwise%20ar-%20bitrary%20function.

Comment: @markleeds, thank you for the link.

Comment: maybe some of the references contain something closer to your problem.